# Electrical wiring issue with Ring Camera

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I am replacing an old floodlight with a new Ring spotlight camera that is on the same breaker as a pre-existing Ring spotlight. I’m adding a second Ring for additional coverage around our property. The first Ring I installed tied into a black, white, and ground wire. It’s been working fine for the past several months. After removing the old floodlight, the wiring coming from the house is black, red, white, and ground. While installing the new Ring I tied into the black, white, and ground—and just put a wire nut on the end of the loose red wire (as shown in image). After flipping the breaker, the new Ring is getting power, but the old one is not.

Do I need to tie the red wire in so that I continue getting power to the pre-existing Ring? Why is there a red wire on this anyways?

[image: wiring]

Comment: How was the old floodlight wired? You should wire the new one up the same way.

Comment: The problem with that is that the old light used an aftermarket photoelectric sensor—I removed it since I don’t need it with the Ring. The red wire was tied into the sensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Connect red to black here

I'm betting that whatever they did had the photocell on *this* light switching the other light on and off.  (You may be able to verify this through some logging facility on the old Ring, as it'd have been turning on at night and off during the day.)  So, I'd tie the red wire here in with the black wire and the new Ring's hot wire, and see if both Rings power up at that point.

Comment: When I first installed the new unit, I attached the red wire to the Rings black wire and left the black wire from the house loose, but the Ring didn’t power on.

Comment: Just to clarify, I need to join the red and black feeds together with the black wire on the Ring?

Comment: @wellington -- yes